# How to test useQuery with Client option

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, apollo-client, ts-jest

I'm trying to mock `useQuery` with `MockProvider` following this [guide](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/). However, my `useQuery` call is using the [client option](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#client) which causes the mock request to not match. How do I get around this without removing the client option?

```
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery({"query", {
  variables: {id: "some-id"},
  client: someApolloClient,  // Removing this fixes my mock
});
```

And my attempt to mock it:

```
const mock = {
  request: {
    query: "query",
    variables: {id: "some-id"}
  },
  result: {
    data: "my result",
  }
};

<MockedProvider mocks={[mock]} addTypename={false}><MyComponent /></MockedProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [mockSingleLink](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/v3.7.12/src/testing/core/mocking/mockLink.ts#L201) helper function to create a mock link for the Apollo client.

You can import the `mockSingleLink` from `'@apollo/client/testing'` module, see the barrel file [v3.7.12/src/testing/index.ts](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/v3.7.12/src/testing/index.ts)

E.g.

`MyComponent.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

export const query = gql`query { hello }`;

export const MyComponent = ({ apolloClient }) => {
  const { data, loading } = useQuery(query, {
    client: apolloClient,
  });
  console.log('data: ', data, ", loading: ", loading)

  if(loading) return <p>loading...</p>

  return (
    <div>data: {data.hello}</div>
  )
}
```

`MyComponent.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mockSingleLink } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import { query, MyComponent } from './MyComponent';
import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

describe('76075063', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    const link = mockSingleLink(
      {
        request: { query },
        result: { data: { hello: 'from link' } },
      },
    );

    const client = new ApolloClient({
      link,
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    });

    render(<MyComponent apolloClient={client} />)
    expect(screen.getByText('loading...')).toBeInTheDocument();

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.queryByText('loading...')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    }, { interval: 1 });


    expect(screen.getByText(/from link/)).toBeInTheDocument();
  })
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/76075063/MyComponent.test.tsx
  76075063
    ✓ should pass (75 ms)

  console.log
    data:  undefined , loading:  true

      at MyComponent (src/stackoverflow/76075063/MyComponent.tsx:10:11)

  console.log
    data:  { hello: 'from link' } , loading:  false

      at MyComponent (src/stackoverflow/76075063/MyComponent.tsx:10:11)

-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 MyComponent.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.712 s
```

package versions:

```json
"@apollo/client": "^3.7.12",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
```